# The exponential function exceeds any polynomial by an arbitrary amount at some point

Tags: real-analysis

Let $p(x)$ be a polynomial.

(a) Use l'Hôpital's rule to show that $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{p(x)}{e^x}=0$.
(b) Use part (a) to prove that for any $\gamma\in\mathbb{R}$, there exists $x\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $|e^x-p(x)|>\gamma$.

So far for (a) I have $\lim_{x\to\infty} p'(x)$ would go to infinity, and the limit of $e^x$ would go to infinity, so we can use l'Hôpital's rule … but even when I use l'Hôpital's rule I am not getting zero.

Comment: Consider inducting on the degree of the polynomial. (Or, if you don't need to be particularly formal, apply L'Hospital $n$ times, where $n$ is the degree of the polynomial)

Comment: You are supposed to use L'Hopital's rule multiple times (the degree of the polynomial).

Comment: So, If I apply L'Hospitals rule $n$ times to $P^{(n)}(x)$ I will eventually get a polynomial that is just a constant times a linear term and can solve to get zero? for example, I can eventually get down to something like $\frac{4x}{e^x}=4e^x-4xe^x$ which when we take the limit would be $\infty-\infty=0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with some low degree polynomials for $p(x)$ (like a constant and then a linear term) to try and see what happens. Also, don't be afraid to use l'Hôpital's rule several times and remember that if you take the derivative of a polynomial sufficiently many times you'll get a constant.

Comment: Careful with going all the way to zero though, if you have $\frac{c}{e^x}$, where $c$ is a constant, you can't apply L'Hospital.

Answer (score 1):

For b.

Assume contrary:

$$(\exists\gamma\in\mathbb{R}),(\forall x\in\mathbb{R}):(|e^x-p(x)|<\gamma)$$

Which means that there exists $\theta\in \mathbb{R}$ s.t

$$e^x=p(x)+\theta$$

but that is impossible, since then

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{p(x)}{e^x}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{p(x)}{p(x)+\theta}=1$$